# Contents of my ~/Desktop directory not actually displayed on the desktop

Tags: nautilus

In my ubuntu 10.10 after configure an external CRT on S-Video in cloning desktop, I've lost my desktop icon and right clicking on it does not show menu and menu bar too.

I've tried to resolve with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
sudo chown -R $ USER: $ USER /Scrivania
```

with following sequence of commands I've gotten again main menu but nothing to do for get back my desktop:

```
mkdir ~/.oldpanel
mv ~/.gconf/apps/panel ~/.oldpanel
gconftool-2 --shutdown
pkill gnome-panel
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Have you any idea to resolve my problem?

I've also posted this question on: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/ubuntu-desktop-lost

thanks in advance
ciao
h.

Comment: What do you mean with 'lost'? Also, reinstalling ubuntu-desktop won't do you any good, it's just a meta package which does nothing. You might want to reinstall the complete gnome environment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm nautilus gnome-panel`. Make also sure that you have selected Gnome as session during login.

Comment: Thanks for answering, for 'lost' I mean that I have lost my icons on desktop I can see and reach them only clicking on menu Places->desktop, If you want I can upload my empty desktop but I do not think that it will be useful.

Comment: @haltman Ah, that will be useful then, please add this information to your question so that it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: @haltman So there is no wallpaper either?

Comment: @DoR No i can see wallpaper but is empty and I can't save on it; may work reinstall complete gnome environment like Bobby suggested? thanks.

Comment: @Jorge Castro thanks for editing my English is really poor

Comment: From your mention of Scrivania, I would guess you have your session in Italian. Do you have both a Desktop and a Scrivania folder in your home folder?

Comment: @misterben I have only Scrivania folder thanks again

Answer (score 5):

This is the same answer I gave on the [Unix & Linux Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3328/ubuntu-desktop-lost/3404#3404). Reposting it here, so the question doesn't show up as unanswered:

> Since the application responsible for
>   drawing the desktop, is nautilus not
>   gnome-panel, you might have more luck
>   by looking at nautilus' settings.
>
> Specifically, if the gconf-key
>   `apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop`
>   is set to false, nautilus won't show
>   any desktop icons. So if the key is
>   set to false, you should change it to
>   true.
>
> If that's not the case, you might try
>   to backup and delete your nautilus
>   settings same way you did with your
>   gnome-panel settings.

Comment: I cannot find this gkonf-key on my file, I have to add it?

Comment: @haltman: Since the default value for that key is true, I would think that it not being there is the same as it being true. However there's no harm in explicitly setting it to true anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a update from Lucid to Maverick and I'm seeing the exact same problem (with all users on my system).  I followed just about every resolution step I could find (including removing all my settings via

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

reinstalling ubuntu-desktop, confirming nautilus' show_desktop setting is clicked, etc.  Still, no desktop icons (even though they are there when I go to Places-->Desktop).

Comment: Finally found a solution.  It turned out to be some problem related to compiz.  Don't ask we why, I never mess with compiz.  Anyway after removing all compiz related packages using synaptic, everything returned to normal

Comment: That's a great think! I've to try it!

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for the delete all COMPIZ packages solution!!! I was just about to freak out figuring out this problem for half a day!!! You really made my day, Frank W.!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrong folder is set as Desktop folder. Go to your home folder and then into **.config** folder (it's hidden, press ctrl + h to see it).

Open **user-dirs.dirs** with gedit and check the line starting with "XDG_DESKTOP_DIR", in your case maybe you have to change "XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop" into "XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/**Scrivania**" if Scrivania is the folder the you want to use as desktop. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering my home folder is already configured in this way

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu Tweak installed then go to

**Applications > System Tools > Ubuntu Tweak**

Now click on **Desktop Icon Setting** under the title **Desktop** from the left side and check box **Show Desktop Icons**

I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I already have this voice selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when upgrading to Saucy--13.10. I tried many CLI solutions listed in many places, all to no avail. based on suggestions above, however, I did the following and it worked!

1. In the Dash, search for dconf Editor and open.
2. On the left hand side of the page are 'menu' items, select the triangle next to 'org' to open that up.
3. Then open 'org', then 'gnome', then 'desktop' and finally click on 'background'.
4. the properties or elements of this option are shown in the box. For all the users in this system I had to click on the checkbox, "show-desktop-icons", solving the original issue asked above. For one of my users I also had to put a check in the "draw-background" box as well since her desktop background wasn't showing as well.

Good luck future travelers to this page!